# meteor how do I create form for users to update their profile details

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

As part of my app development env I have created some seed data that creates users and adds some data to their profile field.

I am now able to display that data in a profile view on my app.

My question is What would be the best way to allow users to add this data on registering?

I have tried a form to do this as part of a "profile" menu set but I was not successful in getting the data updated is the field. The new/updated data was not added.

My template looks like this

```
<template name="profileForm">
<form class="profileform form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder={{firstName}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">Last Name</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder={{lastName}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">E-Mail Address</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder={{email}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">Phone Number</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder={{phoneNumber}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">School</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="school" type="text" name="school" placeholder={{schoolName}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">First year</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="firstschoolyear" type="text" name="firstschoolyear" placeholder={{firstSchoolYear}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">Last Year</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="lastschoolyear" type="text" name="lastschoolyear" placeholder={{lastSchoolYear}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Did you Matriculate Here?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">House Name</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="housename" type="text" name="housename" placeholder={{houseName}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">Country Living In</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="country" type="text" name="country" placeholder={{country}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">City</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="cityofresidence" type="text" name="cityofresidence" placeholder={{cityOfResidence}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label for="inputFirstName">Employment Industry</label> -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input tid="emplindustry" ype="text" name="emplindustry" placeholder={{emplIndustry}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="profilesubmit">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

My JS file looks like this

```
Template.profileForm.events({
  "submit .profileform": function (event) {
// This function is called when the profile form is submitted

var firstname = event.target.firstname.value,
 lastname = event.target.astname.value,
 email = event.target.email.value,
 phone = event.target.phone.value,
 school = event.target.school.value,
 firstschoolyear = event.target.firstschoolyear.value,
 lastschoolyear = event.target.lastschoolyear.value,
 matriculated = event.target.matriculated.value,
 housename = event.target.houseelname.value,
 country = event.target.country.value,
 cityofresidence = event.target.cityofresidence.value,
 emplindustry = event.target.emplindustry.value;

if(Meteor.userId())
 {
    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()},{$set:{
        "profile.firstname": firstname,      
        "profile.lastname": lastname,
        "profile.phone": phone,
        "profile.school": school,
        "profile.firstschoolyear": firstschoolyear,
        "profile.lastschoolyear": lastschoolyear,
        "profile.matriculated": matriculated,
        "profile.housename": housename,
        "profile.country": country,
        "profile.cityofresidence": cityofresidence,
        "profile.emplindustry": emplindustry,
        "profile.joined": new Date(), // current time
      }});
  }
// Clear form
//event.target.text.value = "";

// Prevent default form submit
return false;
  }
});

Template.profileForm.helpers({
  email: function() {return Meteor.user().emails[0].address},
  userName: function () {return Meteor.user().username},
  firstName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.firstname},
  lastName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.lastname},
  phoneNumber: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.phone},
  schoolName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.schoolName},
  firstSchoolYear: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.firstschoolyear},
  lastSchoolYear: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.lastschoolyear},
  matriculated: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.matriculated},
  houseName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.housename},
  country: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.country},
  cityOfResidence: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.cityofresidence},
  emplIndustry: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.emplindustry},
  signedUp: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.joined},
});
```

I have used the Allow function to allow users to edit their profiel field.

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},{ fields: {'profile': 1}});
});

Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId, user, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    if(user._id === userId)
    {
      Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, modifier);
      return true;
    }
    else return false;
  }
});
```

My subscription looks like this.

```
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
```

I strongly believe my lack of programming skill has lead me to leave something important out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at this three packages: [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema), [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) and [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2). Their examples already contain answers to your questions!

Simple-schema will allow you to quickly make, well, schemas for your documents (such as users), indicating the type of each field, the maximum length of arrays or Strings, and so on. Autoform allows you to quickly generate forms from this schema, while Collection2 allows you to bind a schema to a Collection and thus do the checks and cleaning automatically. In the end, if you have to change your document schema (for example by adding a new field), you will just have to change your schema and everything will change accordingly (> the way your form behaves depending on how you did it, the way your collection is managed).

In your case,

```
//Shared code
var userProfileSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName : {
    type : String,
    max : 100,
    defaultValue : ''
  },
  lastName : {
    type : String,
    max : 100,
    defaultValue : ''
  },
  email : {
    type : String,
    regEx : SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
    optional : true
  },
  ...
});

var userSchema = {
  //Add all the fields of a normal Meteor user
  //Then add your own schema:
  profile : userProfileSchema
};

Meteor.users.attachSchema(userSchema);
```

Now your schema is properly defined and attached on the collection.
The third part of the Triforce is now `aldeed:autoform` : Simply generate the form!

```
{{> quickForm 
  schema=userProfileSchema doc=getProfile 
  type=method meteormethod="updateSelfProfile"
}}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will rake a look at those packages

Comment: I have been reading the notes from the three sites and the problem for me is how do I change my current app to use the new ways that are suggested in the readme's? I don't know where to put which code :-). Sometimes I wish the example help would be aimed at beginners rather than code veterans.

Comment: Declare your schemas and your collection binds in common code, your forms in client code =)

Comment: After doing some more reading it seems that these packages do not support relationship type fields. So I would have a relationship between one field ina collection to another collection. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: I don't quite understand where do `doc=getProfile` comes from or what it even is. I've read the documentation but it's far from clear.

Comment: @Yokhen I think it was a hypothetical helper return the current user profile. You would have to define it.

Answer (score -1):

One issue with the way you have done it, is if you introduce something like "roles" which store data on the profile, your code could let someone promote themselves to admin if you don't sanitize what they try and set.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was a bit abrupt. I would really appreciate some advice on how to better structure this.
Should I be using a different collection that the main users one?

Comment: just using a Meteor methods that takes defined parameters and you update defined parts of the profile would be fine